# Functional analysis problems collection with solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, book-recommendation

Could you please advise where I can find problems in functional analysis (covering more or less conventional first course in the subject) with the full solutions. The books that I have found so far include only hints at best.

I guess there may be bits and pieces in real/complex problem books or some online sources, or a textbook with really a lot of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes 3 and 4 of Kadison-Ringrose consist of full solutions to the exercises in volumes 1 and 2. I don't know other examples first hand.

That said, looking at full solutions is likely a bad way to go about functional analysis. You will certainly struggle with some exercises--we all do--but in my view that struggle is part of getting an understanding of the subject.